# How to update the value of child component's props from parent component?

Tags: vue.js

From my `parent` component, I need to trigger a `child` component's portion of code containing a `Firebase` query. Note that in the child component, that code is triggered within the `mounted()` hook (but in order to execute it from the parent component, I suppose I will have to move that code to a method or something).

What is the recommended way to achieve such a thing?

Here's my `parent` component code - simplified for clarity:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <v-btn @click="viewNextWeek"></v-btn>
    </nav>
    <project-row :mon="mon"></new-row-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProjectRow from './ProjectRow.vue';
import store from '../store';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    ProjectRow
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mon: moment().startOf('isoWeek')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    viewNextWeek: function() {
      this.mon = moment().startOf('isoWeek').add(7, 'days');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`Child` component - simplified too:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="monTime">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from '../firebase';

export default {
  props: [
    'mon'
  ],
  mounted() {
    var timesRef = db.collection('times');
    var timesWeek = timesRef.where('date', '==', this.mon);
    timesWeek.get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {      
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        this.monTime = doc.data().time;
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });  
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: [Check this link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201)

Comment: @C2486 my question is about an event in parent component triggering code in child component, not the other way around

Comment: to achieve that, you should use event bus communication between these two components, I mean u should use $emit and $on methods

Comment: Is your component called “project-row” or “new-row-form”? Is the “store” you import in parent component a Vuex store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve that you should use `event bus` communication between these two components. first, you should create a global event bus that can be a central event management and will give you the possibility to access any event from any component within your vuejs app. in your case here, you should emit an event from your parent component  within `viewNextWeek` method and catch it within `mounted` in child component. so every time your `mon` value change within your parent component, will trigger an event to the child component to update `mon` within it.

for more detail for how to use  global event bus, read this article [global event bus article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)